# How can I efficiently generate a Set<Id> from a List<SObject> structure?

Tags: apex

I have a bit of code where I've written a SOQL query that returns a list of SObject records, however I need a `Set<Id>` structure to pass to another method that I don't have control of (and thus can't change the method signature of).

How can I turn my returned `List<SObject>` into a `Set<Id>`? Is the best option just a for loop?

Comment: don't go with the for loop, use a map constr... oh, nevermind :P

Answer (score 202, accepted):

This trick only works on the Id field, but you can use the Map constructor that accepts an SObject list to do this without consuming a script statement for each element in the List.

For example:

```
List<SObject> results = Database.query(someSOQL);
Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(results)).keySet();
```

What this second line does is create a new `Map<Id,SObject>` from the results list [using a special constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm), and then take the map's set of keys via the keySet() method. Then the map falls out of scope and it's heap space is released, leaving you with a very governor-efficient set.

Comment: greased lightning!

Comment: One thing to watch out for if you need to modify the set...  You'll get a `System.FinalException: Collection is read-only` error if you try to add to the resultIds.  To get around that you need to create a new set, e.g., `Set<Id> resultIds = new Set<Id> (new Map<Id,SObject>(results).keySet());`

Comment: or clone the Set `Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(results)).keySet().clone();`

Comment: Worth noting is that if all that you are doing is using the Set<Id> in a bind expression then you can don't need to create the Set and can actually just use the List<sObject>.  For example: `List<Opportunity> opps = [Select Id,Name From Opportunity Where AccountId = :[Select Id, Name From Account Limit 100]];` works.

Comment: Any workaround for a field different from the Id one?

Comment: @jonathanwiesel you have to use a loop and put each key individually in that case. No tricks I know of there.

Comment: Thanks @ca_peterson. Your answer helped me..Keep rocking!

Comment: quickest answer ever.

Answer (score 36):

If you are not using `Dynamic SOQL`, you can skinny this down to a one-liner like this...

```
Set<Id> ids = (new Map<Id, Lead>([SELECT Id FROM Lead])).keySet();
```

This is how you would do it with `Dynamic SOQL` but you must cast...

```
Set<Id> ids = (new Map<Id, Lead>((List<Lead>)Database.query(query))).keySet();
```

This [unresolved bug](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Bug-Can-t-create-a-Map-lt-Id-sObject-gt-from-a-List-lt-sObject/td-p/169168) is why you must cast the returned `List<SObject>`

Comment: Seriously, that issue is still unresolved? I miss Rich Unger so much...

Comment: You don't need to cast to get the `keySet`. You don't care about `values` at all. Just use `new Map<Id, SObject>Database.query(/*query*/).keySet()`. You don't need to wrap the `Map` in parentheses either.

Answer (score 11):

There is an issue with the accepted methodology that can come up if you are not sure each element is in the list only once. It won't matter if you are sure the input is a `SOQL` result, but **if you are writing a utility where you need to get the desired `Set<Id>` without knowing the source of the `List<SObject>`, it may be necessary to adopt a different approach**.

The bug can be demonstrated fairly simply, though I don't have a less contrived use case handy.

```
Lead record = [SELECT Id FROM Lead LIMIT 1];
List<Lead> recordsWithDuplicate = new List<Lead> { record, record };
Set<Id> recordIds = new Map<Id, Lead>(recordsWithDuplicate);
```

The above snippet results in:

> System.ListException: Row with duplicate Id at index: 1

To avoid that, you can use `putAll`, though it may actually be *slower* than just using a `for` loop.

```
Map<Id, Lead> recordsMap = new Map<Id, Lead>();
recordsMap.putAll(recordsWithDuplicate);
Set<Id> recordIds = recordsMap.keySet();
```

---

One more note, I take issue with the contention that the results of `Database.query` must be cast to get the `Set<Id>`. The following compiles and executes without issue:

```
public static Set<Id> getRecordIds(SObjectType token)
{
    return new Map<Id, SObject>(Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + token)).keySet();
}
```