# List<String> of IDs from List<sObject>

Tags: apex

I have a List of sObjects (User) and need to put the ID of each record in this List into a separate List of type String.

I found this related [question and answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8910/how-can-i-efficiently-generate-a-setid-from-a-listsobject-structure), but this puts the ID into a Set (I need it into a List) - the code from this that's not working is below.

```
List<User> users = [SELECT Id, Name, ContactId FROM User];
List<String> userIds = (new Map<Id,User>(users)).keySet();
```

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apex lists have a [constructor that takes a set as an argument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_ctor_3) to you can do this to end up with a list rather than a set:

```
List<Id> userIds = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, User>(users).keySet());
```

(This also relies on this [convenience map constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor).)

Note that although you can use the string type for ID values, it is clearer to use the [ID class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) and that also allows ID-specific methods to be invoked.