# Cross-Referencing a Custom Object's Field Directly in a Condition Using Apex Class and Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, cross-object

Say I have a custom object named `Book__c` with fields `Title__c` and a checkbox named `New__c`, and another custom object named `Author__c` with field `Book__c`, can I use `New__c` field directly with `Author__c` object in a condition?

The requirement is to automatically create a new `Obj_To_Insert__c` record when a new `Author__c` record with `Book__c` field having its field `New__c` set to true.

For example, can I use it like this?

```
List<Author__c> authorList = new List<Author__c>

for(Author__c auth : authorList) {
    if(auth.Book__r.New__c == true) {
        //some code...
    }
}
```

The code above is a snippet from this apex class:

```
public class ThisIsTheClass {

    public static void theMethod(List<Author__c> authorList) {

        Set<Id> id = new Set<Id>();
        List<Obj_To_Insert__c> otiList = new List<Obj_To_Insert__c>();

        authorList = [SELECT Id, Name, Book__c, Book__r.New__c FROM Author__C where Id IN: id];

        for(Author__c auth : authorList) {
            if(auth.Book__r.New__c == true) {
                Obj_To_Insert__c oti = new Obj_To_Insert__c();
                oti.Field1__c = auth.Id;
                otiList.add(oti);    
            } 
        } 

        insert otiList;

    }
}
```

Meanwhile, the apex class is called in the apex trigger below:

```
trigger thisIsTheTrigger on Author__c (after insert) {

    ThisIsTheClass.theMethod(Trigger.New);     

}
```

Comment: Yes you are you facing any issue

Comment: Yes, actually my aim really is to create a new custom object based on that condition I've posted. Each time a new `Author__c` record with that criteria is inserted, a new custom object record must be inserted also. When I use the condition like that, the new custom object is not inserted at all.

Comment: If you are doing this in trigger then in trigger we don't get parent field like this you need to query them.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  yes it is. I am just confirming if it's possible to use it directly like that.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've just modified my post, added the codes I am currently working and also some brief description about the problem I am encountering right now.

Comment: So... is it working? Are you hitting any errors?

Comment: Not at all. No errors whatsoever. But I checked the debug logs and it displays this: `DEBUG|otiList()`.

Comment: Also, `Author__c` record is being inserted using the standard Salesforce save function, so this object is inserted successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Author__c` query cannot possibly return any records. You instantiate a `Set<Id>` and never populate it with anything. Basically, your filter is equivalent to:

```
WHERE Id IN ()
```

This filter will never return any results. Instead of using this `Set`, simply filter on the `List` of records you already have:

```
WHERE Id IN :authorList
```

If you really want to get the `Set<Id>` corresponding to `authorList`, [the correct methodology is](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8910/how-can-i-efficiently-generate-a-setid-from-a-listsobject-structure):

```
Set<Id> recordIds = new Map<Id, Author__c>(authorList).keySet();
```

Comment: I followed your simpler solution: filter the list of records I have. It's working now. Thank you very much.