# Method to return contractID from a ListOfContracts or ListOfContractId's

Tags: apex

Can anyone please help me in writing a method to get the contractId from ListofContractIds or ListOfContracts. I want to use this method when a list of contractId's are passed as an arguments in other method and use this to get list of orders.

```
public static Set<Id> getContractIdsFromSelectedContractList(List<ID> lstOfSelectedContracts)
{
    Set<Id> sContractIds = new Set<Id>();

    for( List<ID> cli: lstOfSelectedContracts)
    {
        sContractIds.add(cli);
    }
    return sContractIds;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need to pass your method a list of `contracts` and loop through the values, could be argued if you need a separate method for this, you can decide that

```
public static Set<Id> getContractIdsFromSelectedContractList(List<Contract> lstOfSelectedContracts)
{
    return new Map<ID, SObject>(lstOfSelectedContracts).keySet();   
}
```

Comment: If that's the question then it's just a dupe of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/8910/2995. And there's a more efficient implementation.

Comment: What? No you just do `new Map<Id, SObject>(records).keySet()`

Comment: @sri If this answer [addressed your problem](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.