# Illegal assignment from Id to List

Tags: apex, soql, list, salesforce-id, string

I have a real quick question.

Usually when I want to get a list of IDs as a List i'll do something like:

```
List<String> voterIds = [select ID, from Vote__c where suggestion__c =: recordId].ID;
```

But for some reason when I try to do it this time I am getting an "Illegal assignment from Id to List"

Can anyone provide some insight into this? I'll be happy to supply code if necessary, thanks in advance!

Comment: i think you are looking for this:- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8910/how-can-i-efficiently-generate-a-setid-from-a-listsobject-structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current syntax you have is incorrect. You [*dereference*](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm?search_text=dereference) a field when you know that your query will return only one record. This is what seems to be the case here where you are dereferencing the `ID` field and thus it is always assumed that there is one record returned from the query, which you are trying to assign to a `List`, resulting in the error.

The correct syntax here should be as:

```
Id voterId = [select ID from Vote__c where suggestion__c =: recordId LIMIT 1].ID;
```

If you want to get the `List` of ids, then you should have something as below (there are other approaches too) and then get the `Id` of the records:

```
List<Vote__c> voterIds = [select ID from Vote__c where suggestion__c =: recordId];
List<Id> idList = new List<Id>();
for(Vote__c v : voterIds) {
    idList.add(v.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As it says, you're trying to assign an Id (a scalar value) to a collection. You need a loop for this:

```
Id[] voterIds = new Id[0];
for(Vote__c record: [SELECT Id FROM Vote__c WHERE Suggestion__c = :recordId]) {
  voterIds.add(record.Id);
}
```

Or, my favorite choice for getting a list of ID values, using a Map to get the values all at once:

```
Set<Id> voterIds = new Map<Id, Vote__c>([
  SELECT Id FROM Vote__c WHERE Suggestion__c = :recordId
]).keySet();
```